# How to copy and paste pictures from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am producing a report which needs to be run daily. I have some pictures in Excel and I want to copy them and paste them into Word. I need them in a certain location. All this needs to be done in VBA.

My proposed way of doing this is by creating template pictures in Word and giving them a name (which can be seen in Home > Select > Selection Panel). I assume that I can then copy the pictures from Excel and paste them over the template pictures (i.e. replacing the template pictures) - I believe this type of technique is possible with Excel-Powerpoint.

(1) If I can execute this, will the pictures from Excel go to the right location in Word and be of the same dimensions as the template pictures?

(2) How do I select the existing named template pictures?

Here is my code so far but at the end, I am missing the ability to select the existing NAMED template pictures...

```
Dim wd As Object
Dim ObjDoc As Object
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
FilePath = "OMITTED FOR PRIVACY REASONS"
FileName = "OMITTED FOR PRIVACY REASONS"

On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName)
Else
    On Error GoTo notOpen
    Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents(FileName)
    GoTo OpenAlready
notOpen:
    Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName)
End If
OpenAlready:
On Error GoTo 0

   wd.Visible = True
   ObjDoc.
```

Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: More code will help with a [mcve], but do you understand how to locate identify an Object within a Worksheet or Document?  I would recommend experimenting with "copy from one place in Excel to another place in Excel", and "copy from one place in Word to another place in Word", and then see if you can join up the middles

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I have included the code so far. As you can see, the ending is incomplete. I have googled but I cannot find how to select existing pictures on Word based on the Names I have assigned on the Selection Panel.

Comment: It's important to know how the pictures are formatted in the Word document. Unlike Excel or PowerPoint, where pictures are always `Shape` objects (meaning they "float") Word can also handle pictures like text characters (`InlineShapes`). As a general rule, it's easier to work with `InlineShapes` when using VBA than with `Shapes` when you want to "replace" them with something else. But in order to advise you we need to know more details about how the pictures are used in the target document...

Comment: Thanks Cindy. Let's say I use InlineShapes.



For some context: Basically the pictures I will be copying over will be pictures of charts I have created in Excel. If I paste over InlineShapes, will they maintain the same format (in terms of size of the chart) or do I need to specify that?



I want to "name" the InlineShapes in the Selection Panel. How do I select named pictures?

Comment: Cross-posted (and answered) at: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/1094015-selecting-images-word.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @CindyMeister Apologies for annoying you and everyone else. I will make sure I notify when I cross-post in the future.

I received a solution on MrExcel of using bookmarks but I need to run this VBA code everyday. I think with that solution, the Word document I am working with will be filled with pictures from the previous days. I suggested using a "template picture" so that I can replace the previous day's images with the latest image. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to think about it?

Comment: I recommend you delete these two questions and start a new one - Stack Overflow is not designed to have forum-type discussions, it's a Q&A site. The short answer, based on what I know, would be to recreate the bookmarks around the InlineShapes so that they can be re-addressed the next time around.